# Output a Single Row from a MySQL Database in a Simple PHP Site without CSS

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small database for a school project that is built like:
Seatnumber | Name | Age | Address

and has around 30 Lines...

I want a blank site with an input field where I can enter one of the 4 values and get as an output the whole row where one value is correct.

So I mean when I had the table like this:

| Seatnumber | Name | Age | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Smith | 24 | Berlin |
| 2 | Mueller | 25 | Berlin |
| 3 | Peter | 24 | Bonn |

I want to enter in the field the number 24 (Probably I need a dropdown field in front of the input field in which category I want to search the value?)
and want to output the complete row 1 & 3 because both had the age "24"

Currently I got this that can output the whole table

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Sitzplan";
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
   echo "Sitzplatz: ".$row['Sitznummer'].". ".$row['Name']." ".$row['Alter']."<br />";
   echo "Wohnort: ".$row['Wohnort']."<br /><br />";
}
```

I Hope you guys can help me with this because I only know Lua and want to have it on a website because of our stupid school rules for not using external programs.

And already many Thanks for the Help!
I hope my English is not so bad that nobody can read it.
And the last thing I created the table simply with PHPmyAdmin if this is important

Comment: To do what you want, you may use the **where** clause in your sql statement (something like: select * from sitzplan where age=?, select * from sitzplan where name = ? , etc....)

Comment: If you need just one query you can try SELECT * FROM Sitzplan where name = ? OR age = ? or address = ? or  Seatnumber = ? .  Replace ? with the value.
This way you won't need to add dropdown in that field and it will search in all values

Comment: ```$sql = "SELECT * FROM Sitzplan WHERE adress=Berlin";
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
   echo "Sitzplatz: ".$row['Seatnumber'].". ".$row['Name']." ".$row['Age']."<br />";
   echo "Wohnort: ".$row['Adress']."<br /><br />";
}```
then it gives me zero output. 
but there are atleast 2 Entries with Adress = Berlin .
I wanted just to test the WHERE entry with static values to see if it works

Comment: I'd expect a syntax error on that query - does it work in phpmyadmin? You probably need single-quotes around the literal string. Always worth testing queries in phpmyadmin as it shows error messages without you having to do anything.

Comment: Once you have it working, change to using Prepared Statements instead of sticking user-supplied values directly into the query. That will help with all sorts of things, including any strings that contain single-quotes.

Comment: Ok Thanks the thing from droopsnoot to test it inside phpmyadmin helped me alot !!
and yeah it was some bracket error....

Now i want just need to do the same thing with a User input field

Answer (score 0):

Use a form and get their values using $_POST

```
<form method="post">
  <select name="field">
    <option value="age">Age</option>
    <option value="name">Name</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="value" placeholder="Value..." />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

On user input, make request a little different :

```
if ($_POST) {
  $field = $_POST['field'];
  $value = $_POST['value'];
  $req = "SELECT * FROM Sitzplan WHERE $field = ?";
} else {
  $req = "SELECT * FROM Sitzplan";
}

$sth = $pdo->prepare($req);
$sth->execute([$value ?? null]); // prevents error if $value is undefined (on no user input)
$results = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Note that I am preparing the request before executing it
Then simply loop $results like you did

```
foreach ($results as $row) {
   echo "Sitzplatz: ".$row['Sitznummer'].". ".$row['Name']." ".$row['Alter']."<br />";
   echo "Wohnort: ".$row['Wohnort']."<br /><br />";
}
```

Comment: So i Figured out that i must use a .html file instead of an .php File right???

but when i do it and wrapped it into the <?php   CODE  ?> then it will show the echo lines as Code Text....
Actual Code: https://pastebin.com/1DWMEz9r

Comment: you may have one php file to do both